# What does "LF runes" mean?

Tags: terminology, diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

I have read the term ["LF runes"](https://diablo2.io/trade/key-of-destruction-t303195.html). What does it mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"LF" usually means "looking for".  It sounds like that person is looking for runes and has 9 keys of destruction to trade.

I've seen "LFG" also used in games, which means  "looking for group", usually used when someone is looking to party up for some sort of activity.

Comment: The answer is spot on, but I also wanted to mention that you may also sometimes see ISO (in search of) used in a similar way, too.

Comment: For completeness: LFT (looking for trades) and WTB/WTS/WTT (want to buy/sell/trade)

Comment: And for even more completeness. You'll often see:
WTB Wisp O Ist
This means they want to buy the Wisp unique ring and are offering an Ist rune in trade.